# pm2 starts many duplicated next.js apps

Tags: node.js, npm, next.js, pm2

I'm trying to deploy Next.js app on local PC.

here's my configuration and package.json files.

```
// package.json
{
  "name": "smarf",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "next dev",
    "build": "next build",
    "start": "next start",
    "lint": "next lint"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "axios": "^0.25.0",
    "modbus-serial": "^8.0.5",
    "mongoose": "^6.1.7",
    "next": "12.0.8",
    "react": "17.0.2",
    "react-dom": "17.0.2",
    "swr": "^1.1.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "autoprefixer": "^10.4.2",
    "eslint": "8.7.0",
    "eslint-config-next": "12.0.8",
    "postcss": "^8.4.5",
    "tailwindcss": "^3.0.15"
  }
}
```

```
// ecosystem.config.json
{
  "apps": [
    {
      "name": "smarf",
      "cwd": "./",
      "script": "node_modules/next/dist/bin/next",
      "args": "start",
      "instances": -1,
      "exec_mode": "cluster",
      "autorestart": false,
      "max_memory_restart": "2G",

      "output": "~/logs/pm2/console.log",
      "error": "~/logs/pm2/onsoleError.log"
    }
  ]
}
```

When I start app with command:

```
pm2 start ecosystem.config.json
```

multiple command windows(which is exactly 11 windows) pops up and closes
then there are 11 same application is running on my computer.
[11 processes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bOmdJ.png)

Deleting 1-10 processes does not affect application.

Did I something wrong with the configuration or is it a bug?

Comment: this is because you're using `-1` as instances, which runs it on all hardware resources

Comment: wow it works perfect! thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @Yash Kumar Verma's comment,

instances should be a number of hardware resources used while running the app.

changing instances from -1 to 1, it works well

Comment: The instances option can be:
    1. an Integer. This spreads the app across a specific number of clusters.
    2. the String ‘max’. This spreads the app across all CPU cores.
You can also use a negative integer. If 4 cores, pm2 start -i -1 will spread 3 clusters (max - integer)

Comment: honor the comment with an upvote if it helped :)